# How do I interpret discontinuous graphs of a probability distribution function (discrete)? Why not simply display it as points?

Tags: probability, distributions, data-visualization

[image]

The graph shows the cumulative probability distribution function for the sum of two fair dice. Why is the probability (y axis) of a given random variable (x axis)shown as lines, and not simply as points?

Also, why is there a large line that extends at x = 12? You can find the table here:

[image]

Comment: cdfs are defined over the whole line. You can readily calculate $P(X\leq 6.75)$ for the sum of two fair dice, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's a *cumulative* distribution function. Take, for example, the line from $x = 2$ to $x = 3$. If you just drew a point at $(2, \tfrac{1}{36})$ instead of drawing a line segment, that would mean that the function isn't defined between $2$ and $3$, when in fact it is. For example, the value of the function at $2\tfrac{1}{2}$ is $\tfrac{1}{36}$. Likewise, the value of the function is $1$ for all $x ≥ 12$, so the graph has a ray starting at $x = 12$.

The table is miscaptioned. It shows the cumulative distribution function, like the figure, not the probability density function  (also known, for discrete variables, as the probability mass function).

Comment: The table's title is incorrect in every important respect: two dice have no probability density function and the values in the table sketch out parts of its CDF.  Would noticing these errors change parts of your answer?

Comment: @whuber Good catch, the table is for the CDF, not the PDF. I disagree that dice have no PDF. A PMF is just a PDF where the measure that the integral is taken with respect to (for computing the corresponding CDF) is the counting measure.

Comment: I won't quibble over PDF vs PMF, because it's a matter of definition.  I think like you about this, but most of the definitions I have encountered insist that a PDF be absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. You say that the value of the function is 1 for all $ x  ≥ 12 $, but you actually meant that the value of the function is 1 for all $ x ≤ 12 $, right?

Comment: @WorldGov No. The CDF $F(x)$ is defined to give you the probability of drawing a value less than or equal to $x$. Since the most a pair of dice can roll is $12$, $F(12) = 1$, and also $F(x) = 1$ for all $x > 12$.